# Словоформы

Tags: морфология

Являются ли словоформы "некто", "некого", "некому", "некем", "не о ком" формами одного и того же слова?

Answer (score 1):

*Некто* - неопределённое местоимение, остальные - формы отрицательного местоимения *некого* (не имеет формы именительного падежа)

Answer (score 0):

Да, все это формы местоимения "кто".

Answer (score 0):

Да, изменяется только окончание.

Answer (score 0):

Местоимение *кто* и *некто* - абсолютно разные слова! Правлильный ответ только у olsa!

Comment: Надо просто голосовать за ответ, вот как я сейчас сделаю...